# Map JSONObject to Java Object

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

I'm developing an Android application that needs to contact an API REST that gives a JSON structured as follow

```
{
     "TEST1": [
        {
            "delegate": true,
            "unit": "mmHg",
            "code": "DIA",
            "read": true,
            "write": true
        },
        {
            "delegate": true,
            "unit": "mmHg",
            "code": "SYS",
            "read": true,
            "write": true
        }
    ],
    "TEST2": [
        {
            "delegate": true,
            "unit": "°C",
            "code": "TEMPERATURE",
            "read": true,
            "write": true
        }
    ]}
```

Now I thought to map the inner object in the array as a simple Java Object (e.g MyObject) with 5 fields, but how can I map the entire Object when I do the retrofit call? I don't think that

```
 List<List<MyObject>>
```

would fit this case since I need to know the keys ("TEST1", "TEST2").
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You don't have a `List<List<MyObject>>` because the outer json is not a json array; you have few instances of `List<MyObject>` packed sequentially under different keys.

Comment: However, you don't really need to know the keys - both `TEST1` and `TEST2` contain the same element (list), so you can just go through all keys of outermost JSON and map their values to `Whatever` representing `List<MyObject>`. Then constructing that little part by hand - assigning those `Whatever`s to fields of your `ClassToMap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the best choice is to map the response in a JsonObject and then take the values with

```
JsonArray test1 = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("TEST1");
```

you could use a counter based on the response's length to make it more dynamic like:

```
int testCounter = 0;    
JsonArray test1 = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("TEST");
```

inside a loop of course

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm following this way, but even if I'm expecting a JSON Object, the server return a 200 response with body "{}", tried same api on Postman it returns the json wrote on my question EDIT: I solved expecting a JSONElement instead of a JSONObject directly. JSONElement can be "transformed" to JSONObject using .getAsJSONObject()